# How to ensure all objects of an array are unique among documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, unique-constraint, multikey

We have a requirement for identifying (and avoid) duplicate records, which are contained inside of an Array of a parent document, ie:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "abc",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 },
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 50 }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  item: "def",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 25 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 5 },
    { size: "M", color: "black", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "L", color: "red", quantity: 2 }
  ]
}
{
  _id: 3,
  item: "ijk",
  stock: [
    { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 },
    { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 10 },
    { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 50 }
  ]
}
```

In this example, items with _id: 1 and _id:3 are duplicate since **all the elements of the array are exaclty the same**

We have been trying to use the following reference but it does not take in consideration all the elements of the array as a whole but just a single property such as the *color*:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#multikey-embedded-documents

If you have any other suggestion or workaround that could help us, we would very much appreciate it :)

Comment: Since u need  to remove duplicates, which item (drf or ijk) should be in the output?

Comment: You might define a hash function for the array that sorts the elements and object fields by some predefined ruleset, and computes a consistent hash of the array.  Then store that value in a field with a unique index.